# How to sort my list so it there are choices in dropdown for ascending and descending?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sorting, knex.js

My goal is to have a dropdown list having choices that will allow the user to sort it either ascending or descending on different categories.

I am having trouble with how to get the 'asc' or 'desc' in there. Naturally, the list sorts asc by default. I am using JS, jQuery, knex, and express.

```
    const sorterOptionList = {
      selected: sorter || '',
      options: [
        { value: '', text: 'No Sort' },
        { value: 'vote_score', text: 'Sort by score;' },
        { value: 'upvotes', text: 'Sort by upvotes;' },
        { value: 'downvotes', text: 'Sort by downvotes;' },
        { value: 'vote_count', text: 'Sort by # votes;' },
      ],
    };
```

Later on in the code, I have this code which does work:

```
  if (sorter) {
      query = query.orderBy(sorter);
    }
```

I am aware that I can sort the list descending by doing this below, but then all of the lists will be descending, solving one problem then creating another.

```
  if (sorter) {
      query = query.orderBy(sorter, 'desc');
    }
```

I have tried escaping of characters to get this to work, something like  `{ value: '\'vote_count' , 'desc\'', text: 'Sort by # votes;' },` Each time I have encountered errors with compiler thinking the desc was another column. I have even tried a `const desc = 'desc';` and then plugged it in where 'desc' is hard coded above and that didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not using `switch(sorter)` instead of `if(sorter)` and modify your query as you wish asc or desc in each case, and you can pass the default case doing nothing

Comment: What would that look like? I considered a switch/case, but couldn't visualize it. Like, what would the function be at the top?

Comment: ok let me help you in this one, does the value in the options represent the column name